# Asp net MVC not works in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I'm having problem com my IIS. My project in 4.5 it works in Visual Studio 2015, however, when I publish in IIS the site doesn't load and only list the files of project as a FTP.

Already it's configured Default Document and Directory in IIS

Anyone know what there is?

**UPDATE: Solved**

I found the problem. I was handling the line and this was problem

```
<add name="AddFileMp3" path="*.mp3" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

Comment: Disable directory listing and then check if you have enabled ASP.NET 4 in IIS installation.

Comment: I did, but I receive a 403. I installed the 4.6 in IIS

Comment: which OS? Windows 7?

Comment: I found the problem. I was handling the line <add name="AddFileMp3" path="*.mp3" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/> and this was problem.

Comment: OK. Maybe you can give a detailed answer below and then accept it. That can help others if they hit the same issue.

Comment: hey which OS your using ? in windows 8 no need to add .mp3  value in web.config,remove then check